# How to adjust Auto Increment?

Tags: mysql, sql

Good day to all. So I have lots of data in excel that i needed to insert in the db but I didn't notice I inserted a duplicate value (cause hr didn't sort it out).

So anyways, here is the deal

```
[id][name]
[1][name1]
[2][name2] // I want to delete this row
[3][name3]
[4][name4]
```

I want to delete row 2. I want to make the id auto adjust like,

```
[id][name]
[1][name1]
[2][name3] // The id will adjust
[3][name4]
```

Is this possible to achieve? Or if not is there a work around I can do?

**PS: My data is already at 50k and I want to delete the rows in the 7k**

Comment: Don't fall into the beginner mistake of thinking a row id key like it is a logical row **number**. Gaps are normal.

Comment: If this is a first load just truncate the table and reload. If it's an update then live with the gaps in the auto_increment column (it should have no business meaning anyway)

Comment: @P.Salmon That's a good idea, and I didn't even think of it.  But, it would not scale well assuming these deletions/recoveries would occur often.

Comment: @P.Salmon Its not my first load. I'm uploading lots of excel. I only get 2 columns from the excels then add to database. When I go to our Month of May data, the data was the same with the april, so I had to remove those data without changing the incremented id.

Comment: So you get a monthly feed for upload and sometimes you get a duplicate months worth which you don't test for but wish to delete the duplicates from a particular month?

Comment: Assuming no FK etc, create new table with autoincrement, insert from existing table, drop existing table, rename new table.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestion, I've already got it. What I did was delete those data, then remove the id column and add the id column with auto_increment again..

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should avoid manually intervening with an auto increment column.  This means, among other things, that when you insert data into your table, you should *omit* the auto increment column, thereby allowing MySQL to automatically assign a value to it.

Perhaps the best solution here would be to have a third timestamp column which records when each record were inserted.  Then, you may use `ROW_NUMBER` to generate the sequence you want, e.g.

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ts_column) id,
    name
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    id;
```

You *might* be able to also order `ROW_NUMBER` using the `id` column, and get the same result.  If you are using a version of MySQL earlier than 8+, then you may simulate `ROW_NUMBER` using user variables.